# Generate and Read NFC Smart Tap Generic Pass in Google Wallet

Tags: android, nfc, google-pay, google-wallet

I'm trying to integrate and use Google Wallet (API and Android SDK) for generating a Generic Pass with Smart Tap enabled, read it using another mobile phone and decrypt the payload.

PRE:

1. Given that there is already a google provided sample:
   https://github.com/google-pay/smart-tap-sample-app
2. The given sample works on my mobile phone reading NFC demo pass from google (see README link of the github project)
3. Given that, at the url https://pub1.pskt.io/c/gn1v07 is is possible to generate random NFC Passes that have publicly available required info (CollectorID, Private Key, Public Key)
4. Given that with pskt passes (3) and sample app (1) i can read those passes

I can't read my custom passes, or, to be precise, I don't receive the correct payload.

My current passes are in "Demo Mode", because I want to be sure they work before ask for publishing.
The google documentation is not clear wether or not this is a blocker or what to do in these case.
I tried to upload the pskt (3) public key (with a different version) in my wallet console, but still doesn't work. The collector ID is the one I have in my google wallet console (converted to byte) and my issuerID has been added to redemptionIssuers.
it seems that smartTapRedemptionValue is not written in the tag, but if I query wallet API it is there:

```json
{
  "cardTitle": {
    "defaultValue": {
      "kind": "walletobjects#translatedString",
      "language": "it",
      "value": "$TITLE"
    },
    "kind": "walletobjects#localizedString"
  },
  "classId": "$ISSUER_ID.$CLASS_NAME",
  "genericType": "genericTypeUnspecified",
  "hasUsers": true,
  "header": {
    "defaultValue": {
      "kind": "walletobjects#translatedString",
      "language": "it",
      "value": "$HEADER"
    },
    "kind": "walletobjects#localizedString"
  },  
  "hexBackgroundColor": "#ffffff",
  "id": "$ISSUER_ID.newPassObject3",
  "smartTapRedemptionValue": "if_you_read_this_it's_great!",
  "state": "active",
  "subheader": {
    "defaultValue": {
      "kind": "walletobjects#translatedString",
      "language": "it",
      "value": "$SUBHEADER"
    },
    "kind": "walletobjects#localizedString"
  }
}
```

If anyone has any clue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the issue, and it wasn't an issue of the pass.

> TL:DR -> Sample app is partial and full of missing pieces.

Digging in documentation and various reverse engineering, I found a 'Service Type' code usage, that was hardcoded in the app:
https://github.com/google-pay/smart-tap-sample-app/blob/192d1760bd8f44e8142dda6611c2a1314b35595b/app/src/main/java/com/google/smarttapsample/GetDataCommand.java#L37

Here is set to Loyalty Cards (0x03). If you want to make it work with generic passes, you have to put Generic (0x12).
In addition, there is an update to GetDataResponse method `getDecryptedPayload`:
https://github.com/google-pay/smart-tap-sample-app/blob/192d1760bd8f44e8142dda6611c2a1314b35595b/app/src/main/java/com/google/smarttapsample/GetDataResponse.java#L258

You should add an "else if" for managing generic cards:

```
// Iterate over service NDEF records
for (NdefRecord serviceRecord : serviceNdefRecord.getRecords()) {
    // Check for `ly` type.   
    if (Arrays.equals(serviceRecord.getType(), new byte[]{(byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x79})) {
        //.... processLoyaltyServiceRecord(serviceRecord);
    } else if (Arrays.equals(serviceRecord.getType(), new byte[]{(byte) 103, (byte) 114})) {
        processGenericServiceRecord(serviceRecord);
    }
}

    private void processGenericServiceRecord(NdefRecord serviceRecord) throws FormatException {
        //in case of general pass `gr` type
        // Get the generic record payload
        NdefMessage genericRecordPayload = new NdefMessage(serviceRecord.getPayload());
        for (NdefRecord generic : genericRecordPayload.getRecords()) {
            // Check for `n` ID = 6e
            if (Arrays.equals(generic.getId(), new byte[]{(byte) 0x6e})) {
                // Get the Smart Tap redemption value
                decryptedSmartTapRedemptionValue = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(generic.getPayload(), 1, generic.getPayload().length));
            }
        }
    }
```

And now reading the pass works correctly!

Comment: Thanks for providing a self answered solution. I changed the original code at the 2 positions but the pass imported from your link (https://pub1.pskt.io/c/gn1v07) isn't readable. Are there other changes necessary (CollectorID, Private Key, Public Key) and where to get the information from ? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Michael, in order to read the pass from the link, you have to keep the service type to loyalty cards (pskt cards are loyalty cards). Other than that, if you click on the three dots of the pass (on your phone), you will see collector id and private key. Use the PrivKey in Utils class (replace the one there) and convert your decimal value of the collector ID to a byte array, then the code should work!

Comment: Wow, that was an easy change and now I can read the PassKit NFC Test Pass card. Do you have any experience in generating your own "custom" cards without a PassKit account ?

Comment: Yes, part of my current work is generating passes from an Android app (wallet button) started from a Google sample, and managing classes and passes using a java desktop library. There is a ton of documentation about it. My cards are generated in google.wallet environment, has nothing to do with passkit

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I'm not able to disclose full source. First post has the github link of the base app and in comments i've put the important parts, I can't provide more unfortunately